# How to remove Administrator rights?

Tags: windows-10

So for the longest time I only had one user on my computer. It obviously has administrator rights. Now since I am studying IT I learned that it is way more secure to use the PC with as less rights as possible, to give malware less power if it happens to affect my system.

I went into cmd, run it as an administrator and wanted to make a second user. I called it Admin and added him into the "Administratoren" group, thus giving him administrator rights.

```
net user Admin /add
net localgroup Administratoren /add Admin
```

Now I wanted to take away the administrator rights on my main user "Rismosch"

```
net localgroup Administratoren /delete Rismosch
```

It succesfully did remove the user "Rismosch" from the group, but I was not able to log into my user again. In the end I added "Rismosch" back into the group, because I couldn't access it otherwise:

```
net localgroup Administratoren /add Rismosch
```

Now "Rismosch" still has administrator rights and I don't know how to get rid of them, without preventing me from logging into the account.

Comment: Your method of doing so is one of the ways to do it. It should have worked. In order for these rights to become affective, you need to log out and back in. If you cannot login, tell us the error message.

Comment: @LPChip I log into the user "Admin". It already has administrator rights, because I can run cmd as an administrator without the permission of "Rismosch". In cmd I type `net localgroup Administratoren /delete Rismosch`. When I log out, the only user I can select is "Admin". It doesn't display "Rismosch" and I can only log in into "Admin". When I add "Rismosch" back into the "Administratoren" group, the user is diplayed again without any damage or loss.

Comment: Try adding Rismosch to the Users group after you remove it from the Administrators group.

Comment: @LPChip It worked. Thanks. And as it works as intendet, with "Admin" having administrator rights and "Rismosch" don't.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is correct.

As you mention that you don't see the user anymore at the login prompt means that your user is not part of the Users group. If you add the user to the Users group, it should work again.